# Facing issue while integrating CustomSpringUtilityJar in SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having two spring applications and the details as follows:

1). Application One: This is a utility jar and its purpose is for CRUD operations on a specific table. We are using spring data jpa and hibernate for achieving the same. Since it is an utility this will not run alone 
and it will be incuded as dependency to other applications. In this case we are using Application2 for that.

2) Application Two: This is a web service application made of Spring boot using yml configuration and also using Application One  for CRUD operations on that table.

Issue: While running application Two(i.e. Spring Boot Application) , I am getting the error message related to the the components, repositories and entities of Application one, 
as the bean is not registered in the configuration. Following are the approaches I used to solve thes:

Approach 1:  In application 2, along with @SpringBootApplication annotation:
added Component Scan, Enity Scan and Enable JPA repositories and in these three annotations we have to include  the package of both  Application1 and Application2. 
This scenario is working fine.

Note: I am not using Approach 1 as I have to make these three changes in every service applications which is going to use this utility jar. So decided to proceed with Approach2

Approach 2:  Created an custom annotation like @UtilJar annotation and configuration class in Application1 and in that configuration class, added the three 
annotations along with the configuration annotation.
In this case, while adding the  custom annotation(created from Application1) in Application2, all the  components and repositories registered in Application1 is registered and error is 
showing related to the repositories registered in Application 2 . The only way I can solve on this is to give EnableJPARepository in Application2 which again similar to
Approach1.

So the root cause what I understood is because of @EnableJPARepository annotation given in the Application1 prompted for this error in Application2. Can anyone suggest me how to proceed on this.

Comment: Do you know the Import annotation? Maybe this could be helpful https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s03.html

Comment: Thanks @SimonMartinelli, I gave import annotation only in the custom annotation to import the configuration class